# Why isn't the root domain also a name server?

Tags: domain-name-system, internet, nameserver, tld

I was trying to understand the inner workings of DNS.

To clarify things, when I say the root domain I mean the root domain without a name.

So when I type `http://www.example.info`, it will check the top-level domain .INFO and find out which IP `example` points to, and all is good.

Yet how does the browser know the IP of the top-level domain .INFO ?

So I was thinking the browser contacts the nameserver of the root domain. And the root domain will tell the browser `.INFO` is at `123.456.123.456`.

But [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_nameserver) states:

> Although any local implementation of DNS can implement its own private
>   root name servers, the term "root name server" is generally used to
>   describe the thirteen well-known root name servers that implement the
>   root name space domain for the Internet's official global
>   implementation of the Domain Name System.

I was wondering why is the root name server not the name server of the root domain ?

Why isn't the root domain also a name server?

Comment: I'm reading the Wikipedia page, and I don't see where it says "that there is one root name server for each top-level domain". I think you mis-read the article.

Comment: @mfinni [quote]Although any local implementation of DNS can implement its own private root name servers, the term "root name server" is generally used to describe the thirteen well-known root name servers that implement the root name space domain for the Internet's official global implementation of the Domain Name System.[/quote]

Comment: @downvoter care to explain the downvote ?

Answer (score 3):

your question isn't actually absolutly clear to me, but i try my best ;-)

example:
www.serverfault.com.

if you read carefully, you will see there is a dot at the end. this dot is actually for the root servers. so you got [host].[domain].[top-level-domain].[root] because there's only ONE root, there is no need for a name after the last dot. the last dot is normally not written (except in configs of name servers e.g. BIND).

Comment: Heys I do know that there's only one root, take a look at the edited question thx =D

Answer (score 2):

The root domain is just an abstract container with all the top-level domains in it (.com, .gov, .net, etc).  It is not a server (or servers).  The **root name servers** (*letter*.rootservers.net) manage the root domain.